# methods called multiple times

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
<li class="cart_item clearfix" v-for="(product, index) in products" :key="index">
<div class="cart_item_text"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success" name="button" @click="increaseQuantity(index)"</button></div></li>
in this for loop has three products. And method called three times.
//script
methods: {increaseQuantity(index) {this.$store.dispatch("incrementQuantity", index);},}
//store.js
mutations:{
INCREMENT(state, index) {state.basket.items = state.basket.items.map(items => {state.basket.items[index].quantity +=1;return items;});},},
actions:{
incrementQuantity({ commit }, index) {commit("INCREMENT", index)},}
```

Comment: So what is the question, exactly? The posted code doesn't seem to call itself three times so there must be an error with how the application was set up or your mouse buttons are actually bouncy? Please create a test app in CodePen, jsFiddle or similar.

Comment: I found my mistake. In store.js i used map() function and it loops three times.

Answer (score 0):

In mutation does not need map() function. It loops three times and it gives me +3 quantity. I do not know what need map() function. Please make me aware of that